# Looking for Popular Mechanics issue on BASIC

Tags: magazine, reference-request

I remember being captivated as a teenager by an issue of **Popular Mechanics** that introduced the BASIC programming language. It would have been late 70's or early 80's.

Anyone know how to find which issue it was?

Answer (score 5):

There's an article in the [August 1979](https://books.google.ie/books?id=TM8DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA66&dq=BASIC%20language&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJz86T_dXzAhWI_7sIHUC0BZ4Q6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=BASIC%20language&f=false) issue introducing BASIC as opposed to an ad mentioning it.

Found by going to the [Google archive](https://books.google.ie/books/about/Popular_Mechanics.html?id=49gDAAAAMBAJ&redir_esc=y) of the magazine, entering 'BASIC language' in the search box, ticking 'Search All Issues' and clicking the 'Search Inside' button.

Comment: Via alternate searches like "basic programming" and "basic computer" I found an article on mini-computers in the October 1972 which has a paragraph mentioning BASIC too. Your find matches the OP's description and date range better, though.

Answer (score 2):

Google has, I believe, all issues [cataloged and available](https://books.google.com/books/about/Popular_Mechanics.html?id=49gDAAAAMBAJ).

I'm not sure what you're looking for but perhaps [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=BtUDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA175&dq=basic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOw5qkztTzAhVNpZ4KHbeeDDsQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=basic&f=false).

Comment: Is there really an article on BASIC in the linked issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it appears all the issues are there.

Comment: I certainly didn't find any